# Can a mobile phone camera be considered equivalent to 10-20mm wide angle lens on a crop body?

Tags: wide-angle, mobile

I want to see the perspective we get from an [10-20mm wide angle lens](https://www.amazon.in/dp/B072639587/?coliid=I2SVPC92TV8A70&colid=3HS7QX5MHTWRL&psc=0&ref_=lv_ov_lig_dp_it) on a crop body DSLR.

Can a [mobile phone camera](https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B077PWBC7J/ref=oh_aui_search_detailpage?ie=UTF8&psc=1) be considered equivalent to 10-20mm wide lens on a crop body?

Comment: What do you mean by "equivalent"?

Comment: Means I want to see the perespective of that wide angle lens without renting it. can i use the phone camera? @PhilipKendall

Comment: @flolilolilo The page on the link in that answer is broken... seems the website have gone defunct.

Comment: @flolilolilo Doesn't mean the question isn't a duplicate, we can put a new answer there, or fix up the old one.

Comment: @PhilipKendall answer there talks about full frame. I have a cropped body.

Comment: Multiply by 1.6 or 1.5, respectively, then. That can easily be brought into that answer, as it is not part of the question.

Comment: @MichaelK I can open that site without problems.

Comment: @flolilolilo Yes but the **content** of the page does not contain an answer to the question and there is no comparison available.

Comment: @MichaelK Okay, that is true.

Comment: This question is presumably linked to my comment on https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/101596/57929 as I suggested a quick test would be to compare to a phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally no. The camera on *most* cell phones provides a field of view equivalent to a 28mm lens on full frame, give or take. That's roughly like the field of view of the long end of 10-20mm on an APS-C camera (15-30mm-e, or a little narrower for Canon). But it doesn't give you a good sense of the wide end, which I assume is most interesting.

There are a few phones on the market with wider lenses, usually as an entirely second camera module — the LG VG35 ThinQ is one such current example. This has a roughly 16mm-equivalent lens.

If you're just trying to get an idea of what a wider field of view will look like, you might try supplemental lenses designed for smartphones. These are terrible in terms of quality so I don't generally recommend them, but they might get you what you want. These usually come in the form of "0.45×" converters — they'll make 28mm into about 13mm. So, if you're just trying to get an idea of what this field of view looks like, that might be a very cheap option.

Comment: But she asked about 10-20mm on a crop cam, so your answer should be yes.

Comment: @jps Only at the long end, though. I'll clarify.

Comment: yes, about 18mm then, quite far from the FOV of a 10mm

Comment: I didn't understand this "field of view of the long end of 10-20mm". What is long end here?

Answer (score 0):

If the smartphone you want to buy offers a field of view that is equivalent to that of a 15-32mm full frame lens, then: yes. As there are tens of thousands of different phones out there, we cannot say for sure if phone A or phone B offers a feature without doing the same research that you would have to do - over and over again, because phone C will most likely differ in relevant ways.

If you want to know about the average field of view of a smartphone, I recommend reading [What is the focal length on your typical cell phone camera?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/38288/what-is-the-focal-length-on-your-typical-cell-phone-camera). The answers also include the necessary equations of you want to do it on your own.